# Preview Layout in Another Language

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is it possible to change the default preview language at Android Studio?
Suppose that right now it preview my values/strings.xml and i want it to prewiev 
values-en/strings/xml.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While editing your layout you can click on the (blue) Globe icon to select the language you want to preview. The icon is between the orientation icon and the SDK icon.

Answer (score 3):

You have a possibility to change a preview language just clicking:

```
Preview -> Language -> Select Language
```

An image instruction

[image]